# PXE Boot, how to make it default to pxelinux.cfg/default?

Tags: pi-4, raspbian-buster, dhcp

I am transitioning a Centos Mini PC acting as a kickstart server to a freed up Pi4b.   I am running Raspberry OS 10.  The problem I have is it is trying to boot the MAC address sequence under pxelinux.cfg rather than defaulting to "default" as I have with Centos.  I am using a menu since this is a lab so I can pick and choose rather than have it predefined in a MAC address file.  The only thing I have under pxelinux.cfg is default but it still goes through all the instances of the MAC until it times out and finally goes to "default".  If it were not so slow it would not be a big deal but its taking 15+min to time out.  Is there a way to make it default to the "default" file rather then go through the MAC sequence or at least speed it up?

Answer (score 0):

I changed it do using dnsmasq with xinetd and works as I wanted.